# How to prevent repeating code using events

Tags: c#

I am a beginner programmer and I feel like I am repeating code unnecessarily.  I want to make a picture puzzle game consisting of 16 pictureboxes.  The problem is that I feel like I have to repeat code for each picturebox's events as in the below example:

```
       Point move;
    bool isDragging = false;
    private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        isDragging = true;
        move = e.Location;
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        if(isDragging == true)
        {
            pictureBox1.Left += e.X - move.X;
            pictureBox1.Top += e.Y - move.Y;
            pictureBox1.BringToFront();
        }

    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        isDragging = false;
    }
```

Comment: You could add a helper method that retrieves the `pictureBoxX` and the necessary other variables (`e.X`, `move.X` - for example) as parameters that is getting called in each `pictureBoxX_...` event function.

Comment: You can point them all to the same set of methods and use `sender` to determine which picture box.

Comment: There are already good answers to this. Just wanted to say get that `IsDragging == true` out of there. The expression inside the brackets of an `if` statement is a boolean expression. Whatever you put inside the brackets will be turned into `true` or `false`. The result of `true == true` is true, and the result of `false == true` is false. Or to put it another way, the `== true` part has no effect, so you can just write `if(IsDragging)`.

Comment: @RichardIrons,It was a good idea.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just create one method for each of your 3 events:

```
private void pictureBox_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    isDragging = true;
    move = e.Location;
}

private void pictureBox_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{

    if(isDragging == true)
    {
        // Luckily the sender parameter will tell us which PictureBox we are dealing with
        PictureBox pb = (PictureBox)sender;
        pb.Left += e.X - move.X;
        pb.Top += e.Y - move.Y;
        pb.BringToFront();
    }

}

private void pictureBox_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    isDragging = false;
}
```

Then go to each of your 16 picture boxes in the designer and set the `MouseUp` event handler to point to `pictureBox_MouseUp` and the `MouseMove` event handler to point to `pictureBox_MouseMove` and the `MouseDown` event handler to point to `pictureBox_MouseMove`. Do this for each of the 16 picture boxes.

Answer (score 1):

Try to trigger same events for all PictureBox Controls

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    isDragging = true;
    move = e.Location;
}

private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    PictureBox pictureBox = sender as PictureBox;
    if(isDragging == true)
    {
        pictureBox .Left += e.X - move.X;
        pictureBox .Top += e.Y - move.Y;
        pictureBox .BringToFront();
    }

}

private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    isDragging = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a new component contained Image component and set dock parent container. Write your drag drop codes into the new component. 
For example,

```
public partial class DraggablePictureBox : UserControl
{
    public DraggablePictureBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets image of inner picture
    /// </summary>
    public Image Image
    {
        get {
            return InnerPictureBox.Image;
        }
        set
        {
            InnerPictureBox.Image = value;
        }
    }

    private void InnerPictureBox_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (isDragging == true)
        {
            this.Left += e.X - move.X;
            this.Top += e.Y - move.Y;
            this.BringToFront();
        }

    }

    private void InnerPictureBox_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        isDragging = false;
    }

    private void InnerPictureBox_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        isDragging = true;
        move = e.Location;
    }

    private Point move;
    private bool isDragging = false;
}
```

Now you have a one drag drop code for images.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you know of a good resource for working with user controls?

Answer (score 0):

One way to combat this would be to put these in methods, for example

```
MovePicturePox(Point move, Point newPos, PictureBox pb)
{
    pb.Left += newPos.X - move.X;
    pb.Top += newPos.Y - move.Y;
    pb.BringToFront();
}
```

These methods can then be called like so

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if(isDragging == true)
    {
        MovePictureBox(move, new Point(e.X, y.Y), pictureBox1);
    }

}
```